# get the childern value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<li class="selector">
     <a>
        <input type="checkbox" value="test" />
    </a>
</li>
```

How do i get the value of checkbox. I have following jquery click event.

```
$('.selector').on('click', function() {
        var vals = $(this).children('input').val();
        alert(vals);    #showing as undefined
    });
```

Comment: why do you wrap 'input' tag by 'a' tag?  I am curious to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method instead:

```
var vals = $(this).find('input').val();
```

If you will have more than 1 input you will need to filter what to get, for example

```
var vals = $(this).find('input').eq(0).val();
```

Will get only first input value

Comment: There's no need for the `eq(0)`. `val()` returns the value of the first item in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use .[find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
 var vals = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
```

- `find()` – search through the matched elements’ child, grandchild, great-grandchild…any levels down.
- `children()` – search through the matched elements’ child only (single level down)

As per your HTML, `checkbox` is `grandchild`